# Select text after comma in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

here is a part of the text:

```
17Braunschweig,Kreisfreie Stadt,40,--,ja,03,1,01,00,00,00
18Salzgitter,Kreisfreie Stadt,40,--,ja,03,1,02,00,00,000,
19Wolfsburg,Kreisfreie Stadt,40,--,ja,03,1,03,00,00,000,K
20Gifhorn,Landkreis,43,--,ja,03,1,51,00,00,000,K,DE914,03
21Goslar,Landkreis,43,--,ja,03,1,53,00,00,000,K,DE916,031
```

I just want the number and the Word after the number (e.g. in the first line: 17Braunschweig).
But the text is over 500 lines long. Is there a way in VS Code to select the part after the word in every line so that I can delete it? Thanks for help.

Expected Output from example:

```
17Braunschweig
18Salzgitter
19Wolfsburg
20Gifhorn
21Goslar
```

Comment: What does "after" mean? Can you give us an expected output and what you have attempted?

Comment: VSC supports regex in their search/replace

Comment: Do you want this to be done in python or through VSC?

Comment: @12944qwerty I want to do it in VSC

Comment: The regexp `,.*` matches everything from a comma to the end of the line. Use that in a find/replace.